# Artifactory shasum fails in Jenkins on expected/returned Chksum

Tags: jenkins, artifactory, centos6.5

During npm install the following error occurs during the install.  The file is located in the npm virtual repo and the npm-local repo. Both files have the same checksum, but for reasons unknown Jenkins/Artifactory build returns with an expected valued different than what is actual.

Workspace, temp dir and cache for node_modules cleaned and error remains. What would cause the variance in returned shasum/chksum values?

```
npm ERR! shasum check failed for /var/folders/zd/d9z45rkj01ddtxxzw_2kzbvnxnn7wh/T/npm-90754-e7f5acef/artifactory.be.sharecare.com/api/npm/npm-repo/foreachasync/-/foreachasync-3.0.0.tgz
npm ERR! Expected: 5502987dc8714be3392097f32e0071c9dee07cf6
npm ERR! Actual:   3475a95a77e4dc2d2800913e6824de77b00cd80a
npm ERR! From:
```

Comment: Did you check if the downloaded archive in the NPM cache is a valid archive and identical to the one you have in Artifactory?

Comment: The archive is valid and is identical to the one in artifactory.. We have since deleted the artifactory artifacts and deployed again with the same error appearing in the npm--repo.  Does it matter that the same artifact appears in npm-repo and npm-local?

Comment: What is the SHA1 checksum you see for the foreachasync-3.0.0.tgz file inside Artifactory? if you have it in more than one repository, do they have the same checksum?